# ExtJS 4 or 4.1 MessageBox Custom Buttons

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
    title:'Messagebox Title',
    msg: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
    buttons: {yes: "Some Button 1",no: "Some Button 2",cancel: "Some Button 3"}
});
```

ExtJS 4 or 4.1 does not support this code. Buttons do not show.

Answer (score 19):

Just found out how to do this, hopefully it helps someone.  As you can see you can handle the buttons however you want.  Note that the framework only has 4 buttons by default and that is a limitation that won't be easily overcome. In the source there are multiple loops hard coded from 0 to < 4.

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
    title:'Messagebox Title',
    msg: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
    buttonText: {yes: "Some Button 1",no: "Some Button 2",cancel: "Some Button 3"},
    fn: function(btn){
        console.debug('you clicked: ',btn); //you clicked:  yes
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that inside the method show, since the buttons config in the method takes as an argument a number identifying the buttons to show.
What you can do is to predefine your message box and then just show it.

```
 var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
     width:300,
     height: 100,
     buttons: [
      {text: 'My button 1'},{
        text: 'My button 2'}
    ]
});

win.show({
     title:'Messagebox Title',
     msg: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Following Code:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
    title:'Messagebox Title',
    msg: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
    buttonText: {                        
        yes: 'Some Button 1',
        no: 'Some Button 2',
        cancel: 'Some Button 3'
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                Ext.override(Ext.MessageBox, {
                    buttonText: { yes: "Sí", no: "No", cancel: "Cancelar" }
                });
            })();
    </script>
```